# How to pause a script just for a fraction of a second in PHP using the SLEEP() function?

Tags: php, time, sleep, wait

```
sleep(1);   #waits/sleeps for one second then continue running the script
```

Q1. How to make this 1/100 of a second? which of these work: `0,01`  or `0.01`  or `.01` ?

Q2. What are alternatives? `wait();` or `snap();` ?? how do they differ (more/less precise)?

Comment: A better question is "Is `sleep(x)` the best approach to solve ___________"? What is the problem you're trying to solve with `sleep()`? It's a powerful tool that is abused in *every* language when there are better solutions.

Comment: @glowcoder +1: was unaware of the language-agnostic abuse shadowing sleep

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Q1. How to make this 1/100 of a second? which of these work: 0,01 or 0.01 or .01 ?

None of the above!

[`usleep`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php) is what you want for fractions of a second.  `usleep(100000)` will sleep for one tenth of one second.

Your other options are [`time_nanosleep`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time-nanosleep.php) which takes both seconds and *freaking nanoseconds* (one billion of which are one second), and [`time_sleep_until`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time-sleep-until.php), which will sleep until a particular unix timestamp has been reached.

Be aware that your system might not have millisecond resolution, no less nanosecond resolution.  You might have trouble sleeping for precisely tiny, tiny amounts of time.

Comment: @Alix, you are probably right, given the context is sub-second sleeping.

Answer (score 4):

Late answer... but you can use [time_nanosleep()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time-nanosleep.php), i.e:

To sleep for `1/10` of a second (`0.1`):

```
time_nanosleep(0, 100000000);
```

---

To sleep for `1/100` of a second (`0.01`):

```
time_nanosleep(0, 10000000);
```

---

To sleep for `1/1000` of a second (`0.001`):

```
time_nanosleep(0, 1000000);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [usleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php) in which you can pass in microseconds,

so for your case you can call `usleep(10000)` to sleep for 1/100 of a second.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [`usleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php) or [`time_nanosleep()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time-nanosleep.php).

As for your second question, all these methods come with a high level of precision however I would advise you to test on your specific system if it's critical.